# Codeigniter: set_value not re-populating correctly array form field

Tags: forms, codeigniter, validation, populate

I have a form with CI validation that uses arrays as input names. The view initially has this code:

```
<input type="text" name="feed_urls[]"
   value="<?php echo set_value('feed_urls[]', ''); ?>" >
```

which when loaded into the browser translates correctly to this:

```
<input type="text" name="feed_urls[]" value="">
```

Then through Jquery the user may add more identical `<input>`'s to the DOM before submitting, so in the end what is POSTed could be e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="feed_urls[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="feed_urls[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="feed_urls[]" value="">
```

Now, if the submitted data passes validation, all is fine and gets stored in DB. But if validation fails, the controller sends back to the view but I don't see the N `<input>`'s of the POSTed form. I only see one and it's empty, which is understandable because I don't supply a 2nd argument to set_values(), but then again what was expected was to see the inputs be re-populated through the $this->input->post(feed_urls) array with the POSTed data that was invalid.

I do verify at the controller that $this->input->post('feed_urls') has the POSTed content (invalid or not) just fine.

I've read the CI user guide docs on using [validation with arrays as field names](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields)

Any ideas on what's the correct use of set_value()? By correct I mean that on validation failure, I get the N inputs that were POSTed, correctly re-populated one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<input type="text" name="feed_urls[]" value="<?php echo set_value('feed_urls[0]'); ?>">
```

I've tested it on CI 2.0 but it should work also in previous versions.

Cheers!

Comment: But how does one know how many of such inputs one should output? Anyway to get the size of the array at least?

Answer (score 0):

As you supply only a small bit of your code, I can only give you a hint on what I think is your main problem.

The n element of input array can be populated by using jQuery as follows:

```
$("[id^=feed_urls]").eq(0).val(someURL);
$("[id^=feed_urls]").eq(1).val(someURL);
$("[id^=feed_urls]").eq(2).val(someURL);
```

and so on.